# System Crash due to VLC in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, vlc, crash

04 and I opened a vedio from my google drive from files and opened it with vlc and I am not sure but I thought it was deleted , so vlc took so much time and doesn't played it also didn't gave me error so I quit vlc. After closing the program it was on in the topbar so I left clicked it and selected the option to quit but it was not closing the app and I repeated this step but no success. I decided to close vlc from system-monitor and I **ended the correct process named vlc** and after that my system frosed and my Ram which is 4GB and Swap which was 2GB was fully Utilized and I was not getting any responce even mouse icon was not moving. After some time I got some responce and I immediately restarted and now the system is stable but what should I do if it happen in future?

Comment: 2GB is likely insufficient for most modern uses of desktop environments. Just a browser with a number of tabs could run through all of your memory in no time at all. Consider increasing the swap space. As for the video issue, it is impossible to answer without knowing anything about the video or the hardware of your machine.

Comment: When VLC will not close from the top bar it has crashed you need to reboot the machine not just force close it. Trust me I know this program and have experience the same issue. VLC is a ram hog tou need more ram but try what Matigo said.

Comment: I don't have a problem with swap size but this problem was new, I use vlc everyday and its ok and it never use that much ram and swap.The program was closed and no vedio was played then to it frosed my laptop. My ram usage is everytime low and also swap is never used by my laptop. @Matigo

Comment: Yes @David as aoon as I got control of my laptop I rebooted and the issue was solved but what if it happened again how can I solve it if my laptop frosed completely?

Comment: In the past year it has happened to me maybe 3 times. That is life it happens.

Comment:   Right.@David